# QT, прототип класса Robot

Tags: qt, c++

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как в qt называется класс, прототип класса Robot в Java? То есть, чтобы там были ф-ии взять цвет пикселя по координатам, передвинуть курсор мышки, …

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: пишу в Qt и не знаю такого класса. Передвинуть курсор - получаешь объект курсора и двигаешь. Про пиксели - смотря с чем работаешь.

Comment: просто взять произвольный пиксель с экрана.

Comment: со всего экрана или виджета?

Comment: своего, в общем спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю такого класса, о котором вы говорите (может он и есть, но я не знаю). Но все описанные задачи можно сделать без него. Например, взять весь экран в QPixmap

```
QWidget *scr = QApplication::desktop();
WId w = scr->winId();
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(w,0,0,scr->width(), scr->height());
```

и получить цвет пикселя

```
QRgb color = pixmap.convertToImage().pixel( 0, 0 );
```

Насчёт движения мыши:

```
QCursor *cur = new QCursor;
cur->setPos(100,100);
```

Comment: Такой подход не сработает в случае нескольких экранов у пользователя. Нужно для каждого из них в отдельности вызывать [`QDesktop::screenGeometry(index)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdesktopwidget.html#screenGeometry) и передавать возвращаемый `QRect` методу `QPixmap::grabWindow`.

Comment: вообще, можно не "грабить" весь экран, а брать чуть ли не один пиксель. Так что это был просто пример=)